# function which terminates a subprocess if it exceeds x seconds in a for loop in matlab

Tags: multithreading, matlab

I am running a very large loop for a optimization problem. I want to automate the process where if my solver donot reach a specific solution in x seconds/minutes, I want to terminate this subprocess and move on to next set of parameters. I am not looking for a function to terminate the loop (such as break), but a function or a method that terminates the subprocess which is taking more than x seconds/mimutes, so that loop can continue.

```
for i = 1:N

run optimization with a random set

if the time to execution takes longer than x seconds/minutes
terminate this optimization
else 
save result
end

end
```

I tried looking for timer callback functions, but I couldn't find how to terminate the command automatically. I think some sort of multithreading is required. Can someone point me how to do it in matlab or any other language.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/255067) in the MATLAB central. It is from 2009, but I'm not aware of any new possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply the command [`break`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html) and two loops to solve your problem.

You can try something like that:

```
% // Create mxn dimension matrix of parameterSet. n parameters for each m epoch

for ii = 1 : m
   % // Initialize the parameter
   parameters = parameterSet(ii, :);

   launch = tic;

   for jj = 1 : N

       % // run optimization with a random set

       if toc(launch) > x    % // In terms of second
          break;
       else
          % // save result
       end
   end
end
```

Comment: @Schorsch - Yeah sure. I have just edited my answer upon your ask. I had thought this way for OP' s problem. I suppose he had edited his question upon my answer (you can check his edit and when) but I didn' t realise it because he didn' t comment on my answer. Therefore I think I don't deserve to be down voted, whatever..

Comment: reversed. simple solution.